# Accessing SQLite database from Assets Folder without copying to user's data folder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-assets

In my iOS app I have a large (270MB), pre-populated, read-only sqlite database.  I keep the data in the app bundle and query it with no problems.  I do not copy the database to the user's documents folder, because it would be pointless in this situation to take up more space with a duplicate database. I have a separate much smaller database I copy to the user's documents folder to store the user's preferences. The app works just fine.

Now I'm trying to port my app to Android using Android Studio, but it does not seem possible to access the database from the assets folder.  I have found plenty of documentation on database helper classes for Android, which I have tried, but the approach always seems to be to copy the database from the assets folder to the user's data folder.  This would be a waste of space and also in my experience the app is unable to copy the database without crashing (maybe because of the size? I had no problems copying a smaller test database).

Is there a way to access the database without copying it to the user's data folder?  If not can anyone think of another way of approaching this?

Comment: No There is no way. This is not _iOS_.

Comment: no, there is no such physical thing like "assets folder" on the device

Comment: You cannot have iOS completely ported to Android, although Android provides lots of customizations but there are things that Android can't do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No, You can not directly write into the files of ASSETS folder in your application as the resources folders are read-only.**

So You have to compulsory copy your database first from your assets folder to your sdcard and then only you will be able to read & write into it.

Comment: I figured that you couldn't write to the assets folder, but I was hoping there was some way you could open it and read from it, but guess not.  Thanks

Comment: Downvoted. He specifically asked about READING from it, so this answer makes no sense at all.

Answer (score -1):

As GrIsHu said, you can only read database from asset folder. If you need to do more operation like create, update,  delete you can do a tricks. Copy the database from assets folder to storage and then you can do anything you want.

Here is a quick example of [Working with Android Pre Built Database.](https://github.com/jakirseu/Android-Pre-Built-database)

There is a easy to use library too for accessing database from assets folder. You can check [Android SQLiteAssetHelper] here.[2](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that all the answers and tutorials tell you to copy it, even if you only want to READ from it, as the OP said too.